# Table name alias scope in sub-select query

Tags: mysql

I am getting `Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'`.

```
SELECT id, username,
    coalesce(
     (SELECT name from company c 
        INNER JOIN user_company uc 
        ON uc.user_id = u.id 
        AND c.id = uc.company_id), 'NOT-AVAILABLE' 
    ) companyname
FROM `user` u
```

Comment: does the user table actually have a column id?

Comment: Try changing the subquery to: SELECT name from company c 
    INNER JOIN user_company uc 
    ON c.id = uc.company_id WHERE uc.user_id = u.id

Comment: This is a `gasping at straws` answer, so I'll leave it as a comment :) Move the `uc.user_id = u.id` into a `WHERE` clause of the correlated sub-query?  *[Also, couldn't you just LEFT JOIN that in the main query?.]*

Comment: Dems - yes it works that way - excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, the correlation can't be placed within the `JOIN` of the correlated sub-query.

It can, however, be placed in the `WHERE` clause of the correlated sub-query.

```
SELECT
  id,
  username,
  coalesce(
    (SELECT name
       FROM company      c
 INNER JOIN user_company uc
         ON c.id = uc.company_id
      WHERE uc.user_id = u.id
    ),
    'NOT-AVAILABLE'
  ) companyname
FROM
  `user` u
```

That answers your explicit question; why your query failed syntactically.

I would, however, replace the whole correlation with a simple `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.username,
  COALESCE(c.name, 'NOT-AVAILABLE') companyname
FROM
  `user` u 
LEFT JOIN
  `user_company` uc
      ON uc.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
  `company` c
    ON c.id = uc.company_id
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix it:

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.username,
       COALESCE(aux.name, 'NOT-AVAILABLE') as 'companyname'
FROM `user` u
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT user_id, name from company c 
    INNER JOIN user_company uc
    ON c.id = uc.company_id) aux ON aux.user_id = u.id
```

---

Another way to fix it:

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.username,
       COALESCE(c.name, 'NOT-AVAILABLE') AS 'companyname'
FROM `user` u
LEFT JOIN user_company uc ON uc.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN company c ON c.id = uc.company_id
```

Comment: There is a typo in the first query - but both work - thank you!

Comment: @user1421214 then you should vote up and accept the answer. Typo fixed! :)

Comment: +1 from me - but I accepted Dems answer... sorry but I really appreciate your answer too. :)

Comment: ohh no problem :) didn't notice his answer ^^

Comment: actually he posted a comment at first - I tried that it worked - and then I checked your answers - anyway thanks